# BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor() returns but not Items inside

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

*Briefly:*

Bundles which contain items from a `VirtualPath` (Served by custom VirtualPathProvider) don't work. Hash isn't generated in the `v=` and resolving them shows the `.Items` property as empty.

*Detailed:*

Suppose we have a bundle registration:

```
  bundles.Clear();
  bundles.ResetAll();
  BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css")
           .Include("~/Content/site.css"));
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/admin/somestyle")
           .Include("~/Areas/Admin/Content/css/aaa2.css"));
```

Some notes here:

1. `~/bundles/admin/somestyle` physically doesn't exist.
2. `~/Areas/Admin/Content/css/aaa2.css` is a virtual path which is handled by a custom `VirtualPathProvider`
3. `~/bundles/css` is served by default `MapPathBasedVirtualPathProvider`

Relevant part of current Web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"/>
  <handlers>
     <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
     <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
     <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
     <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
     <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
     <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
     <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
     <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />

     <add name="AspNetStaticFileHandler-TIFF" path="*.tiff" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
     <add name="AspNetStaticFileHandler-GIF"  path="*.gif"  verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
     <add name="AspNetStaticFileHandler-PNG"  path="*.png"  verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
     <add name="AspNetStaticFileHandler-JPG"  path="*.jpg"  verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
     <add name="AspNetStaticFileHandler-CSS"  path="*.css"  verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
     <add name="AspNetStaticFileHandler-JS"   path="*.js"   verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
     <add name="AspNetStaticFileHandler-WOFF" path="*.woff" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
     <add name="AspNetStaticFileHandler-TTF"  path="*.ttf"  verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
     <add name="AspNetStaticFileHandler-MAP"  path="*.map"  verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
   </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
```

Routing entries:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
 AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
 RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

#### Test Drive:

### 1. Trying to access the `.css` files directly:

`http://localhost:1010/Areas/Admin/Content/css/aaa2.css` - File found => Custom VirtualPathProvider did his job.

### 2. Trying to resolve `bundles` from HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var bundleVirtual = BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor("~/bundles/admin/somestyle");
    var bundleVirtualUrl = BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/admin/somestyle");

    var bundleOrdinary = BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor("~/bundles/css");
    var bundleOrdinaryUrl = BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/bundles/css");

    return View();
 }
```

- `bundleVirtual` is found but .Items property is empty.
- `bundleVirtualUrl` is **/bundles/admin/somestyle?v=** notice that **v=** has no hash value.
- `bundleOrdinary` is found, .Items has one entry `~/Content/site.css`.
- `bundleOrdinaryUrl` is **"/bundles/css?v=6bMbVqKBetPV3UISUSkpqR5wiBsbzK_c6J21LUZAzaU1"**

## Question:

Why resolving "~/bundles/admin/somestyle" shows that there are not Items added, even if the item is registered and the VirtualPathProvider handles it correctly?

#### Related links:

1. [ASP.NET Bundling/Minification and Embedded Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764002/asp-net-bundling-minification-and-embedded-resources)
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/728146/ASP-NET-MVC-bundles-internals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register your VirtualPathProvider **before bundle registration**, in order to be able to find your files.  Any files not found will not be included in bundle.Items

```
var vpp = new MyVirtualPathProvider();
BundleTable.VirtualPathProvider = vpp;
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Unless of course you already have it registered as HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.